# Projection WGS 84 is slightly displaced referring to a hillshade in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, hillshade

I have a hillshade and a vector layer. The vector layer is slightly displaced referring the hillshade. About lat=100m and long=175m

The CRS of the project is EPSG:3397 - PD/83 / Gauss-Kruger zone 4.

The CRS from the vector layer: `+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`.

How can I place the vector layer on the right place in QGIS
I tried it with the `+towgs84=...` attribute. But this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data from Germany, I would suggest `EPSG:31468`. Looks like EPSG:3397 has not yet received proper towgs84 parameters.

EPSG registry remarks for PD/83:

> Consistent with DHDN (CRS code 4314) at the 1-metre level. For low
>   accuracy applications PD/83 can be considered the same as DHDN.

Comment: Great, thank you! When I change my Project CRS to `EPSG:31468` the vector layer is in the right place.

Comment: this is a common error within Qgis. DHDN Gauss Krüger 4 is very often misinterpreted as PD/83 ... when loading a layer. This also happens everytime when you create a layer within the GRASS toolbox, it's pasted to the canvas in the wrong CRS, so you always have to check and correct it.